# Permission denied after pg_upgrade on RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

After trying to upgrade a shadow-copy of our PostgreSQL 9.6.6 RDS instance to 10.4, most operations on the database, including those done with a "root" user (the one created when setting up the database), result in an error like this:

```
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for schema public
  Position: 15
```

Another example is a query like `select * from example_table limit 100;` which results in the error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "example_table" does not exist
  Position: 15
  ERROR: relation "example_table" does not exist
  Position: 15
  ERROR: relation "example_table" does not exist
  Position: 15
```

However, I am able to execute `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';` which correctly lists all my tables

The upgrade logs don't seem to show anything unusual. I've been unable to find any RDS-specific instructions on upgrading from 9.x to 10.x so I assumed that the normal upgrade procedure in the interface (which I've used in the past and seems to be using a `pg_upgrade` operation) would "just work". Is there anything I'm missing?